# Bad CSS in a html file from external package breaking precompilation in Rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error, asset-pipeline, node-modules

I'm having a situation where some bad CSS in a html file from an external package breaks the `rake assets:precompile` for my Rails project. I understand that precompiling your dependencies is something that's done on purpose, and also seems like a good idea (as long as they pass through without errors), and I'm not sure what the standard protocol is for when an external package breaks your assets.

Breaking asset:

```
node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browserify-zlib/node_modules/pako/doc/index.html
```

Error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "  background": expected comma, was ": -moz-linear-g..." (sass):192
```

I have a couple of ideas on how I might do this:

1. Limit precompilation to app/assets/* (don't precompile gems and external dependencies)
2. Exclude html files from precompilation (I'm confused about getting a CSS error from a html file) - but I might still get errors from other file types from external packages
3. Exclude anything in `node_modules` - I'm not sure how I'd do this in practice.

`pp Rails.application.config.assets.paths` gets me this:

```
p Rails.application.config.assets.paths
["/myapp/app/assets/images",
 "/myapp/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets",
 "/myapp/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 "/myapp/vendor/assets/stylesheets",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/rails-assets-speakingurl-6.0.0/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/rails-assets-speakingurl-6.0.0/app/assets/templates",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/rails-assets-dropzone-4.0.1/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/rails-assets-dropzone-4.0.1/app/assets/stylesheets",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/rails-assets-mailcheck-1.1.1/app/assets/documents",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/rails-assets-mailcheck-1.1.1/app/assets/images",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/rails-assets-mailcheck-1.1.1/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/rails-assets-backbone-1.1.2/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/rails-assets-backbone-1.1.2/app/assets/templates",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/rails-assets-underscore-1.8.3/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/rails_admin-0.7.0/app/assets/images",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/rails_admin-0.7.0/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/rails_admin-0.7.0/app/assets/stylesheets",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/nested_form-0.3.2/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/jquery-ui-rails-5.0.5/app/assets/images",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/jquery-ui-rails-5.0.5/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/jquery-ui-rails-5.0.5/app/assets/stylesheets",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/font-awesome-rails-4.4.0.0/app/assets/fonts",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/font-awesome-rails-4.4.0.0/app/assets/stylesheets",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/remotipart-1.2.1/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/selectize-rails-0.12.1/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/selectize-rails-0.12.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/codemirror-rails-5.5/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/codemirror-rails-5.5/vendor/assets/stylesheets",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/jquery-rails-4.0.4/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.0/lib/assets/javascripts",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5.1/assets/stylesheets",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5.1/assets/javascripts",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5.1/assets/fonts",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5.1/assets/images",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/font-awesome-sass-4.4.0/assets/stylesheets",
 "/usr/local/bundle/gems/font-awesome-sass-4.4.0/assets/fonts"]
```

Comment: The only way around it would be to manually edit the file you're trying to change. You won't be able to call the file in production, the point of pre-compilation is to make sure all your files are kept local to your app.

Comment: That'd be a problem since I'm deploying Docker and as containers are ephemeral, the dependencies get reinstalled and the files re-created on every build. Changing the file manually is just not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading (or downgrading) your 'sass-rails' gem.

Don't forget to restart the server after bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved with a change to require a dependency through Browserify instead of Sprockets (that was the way it was meant from the beginning but there was a small error in `application.js`). I no longer get a CSS error from the file as it doesn't go through the asset pipeline.